# How can i solve php upgrade problem

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am using a plugin that works on Woocommerce.
While no error occurs on PHP 7.2 (eg 7.3) I get an error like the following in 7.2.  The developer team is not helping.  How can I resolve this error?  It is probably caused by a foreach loop defined in the plugin.  However, I am not sure how to find this cycle.  I've been researching for about a week.  I could not find a solution.
I looked at a change that came with new versions of PHP.  I could not see any change regarding the foreach loop.  I searched for similar problem on other platforms.  Unfortunately, I could not find it.

invalid argument supplied for foreach() in woocommerce/includes/wc-template-function.php on line 2735.

Comment: Hi, it's difficult to suggest without looking at the source codes.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer. The problem has answered by plug-in support team.